# Android write to BLE not permitted even the property WRITE is present

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I set the BLE character read, notify and write:

```
char_props.broadcast      = 0;
char_props.read           = 1;
char_props.write_wo_resp  = 0;
char_props.write          = 1;
char_props.notify         = 1;
char_props.indicate       = 0;
char_props.auth_signed_wr = 0;
```

and:

```
BLE_GAP_CONN_SEC_MODE_SET_OPEN(&cccd_md.read_perm);
BLE_GAP_CONN_SEC_MODE_SET_OPEN(&cccd_md.write_perm);
cccd_md.vloc = BLE_GATTS_VLOC_STACK;
```

I checked the properties of the character from Android, it is 26, So I think it is correct.

```
I/System.out: mLockCharacteristic.getProperties(): 26
```

Android has the following definitions:

```
public static final int PERMISSION_WRITE = 16;
public static final int PERMISSION_WRITE_ENCRYPTED = 32;
public static final int PERMISSION_WRITE_ENCRYPTED_MITM = 64;
public static final int PERMISSION_WRITE_SIGNED = 128;
public static final int PERMISSION_WRITE_SIGNED_MITM = 256;
public static final int PROPERTY_BROADCAST = 1;
public static final int PROPERTY_EXTENDED_PROPS = 128;
public static final int PROPERTY_INDICATE = 32;
public static final int PROPERTY_NOTIFY = 16;
public static final int PROPERTY_READ = 2;
public static final int PROPERTY_SIGNED_WRITE = 64;
public static final int PROPERTY_WRITE = 8;
```

But when I write, I got error:

```
E/BleManager: onCharacteristicWrite error 3

public static final int GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMITTED = 3;
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: It means that the **remote device** does not permit you to write to **that** ***characteristic*** (although it has set the writable bit in the properties...)

Comment: OK. Does it mean I can never write to it?Why it doesn't permit me to write even it has the writable bit set?

Comment: @JonGoodwin, I have double checked my code, it is the right characteristic:

Comment: final byte[] command = new byte[] {(byte) (data)};
  mCharacteristic.setValue(command);
  writeCharacteristic(mCharacteristic); where data is an "int". Is this the correct way to write?

Comment: From BLE side, I defined #define MY_UUID 0xC935; from Android side, I got uuid by UUID.fromString("dca8c935 ... Android could get the notification from BLE, the value is correct... but write to BLE is not permitted...

Comment: **BluetoothGattCallback** Callback indicating the result of a characteristic write operation.

If this callback is invoked while a reliable write transaction is in progress, the value of the characteristic represents the value reported by the remote device. An application should compare this value to the desired value to be written. If the values don't match, the application must abort the reliable write transaction." [BluetoothGattCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback)

Comment: Is the error "BleManager: onCharacteristicWrite error 3" reported by Android, or by remote BLE? If it is Android that reported this error, maybe there is something wrong with the Android. I rebooted Android, problem still exist. The notification happens every 10 seconds, it should not always conflict with the write, which is triggered by the onClick of a button.

Comment: Please double-check the peripheral again, since that is the device that denies the write - not Android.